# Check if a specific Wireless connection is connected with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to this and still learning so please forgive my syntax.

What I am trying to do is have a batch file to check to see if a wireless connection is connected.....If so ....then I can finish the code from there...

So far I have

```
IF netsh interface show interface name="CMP********" Goto :SUCCESS 

IF NOT netsh interface show interface name="CMP*********" Goto :FAIL 

:SUCCESS
ECHO You have an active Internet connection
pause
goto END

:FAIL
ECHO You have an nonactive Internet connection
pause
goto END

:END
```

I know this is not right but just need some help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:==
set "network_to_check=LAN1:"
:==
set nt=0
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%$ in ('ipconfig') do (
    set "line=%%$"
    ! echo %%$ >&2

    if "!line:~0,1!" neq " " (
        set /a nt=nt+1
        set _nt!nt!=!line!

    ) else (
        ! echo ----
        for /f %%# in ("!nt!") do (
            ! echo a:%%#
            ! echo --- %%# ---

            set "_nt!nt!=!_nt%%#!  !line!" 

        )   
    )
)

set _nt|find /i "%network_to_check%" >nul 2>nul||(
    echo network not found
    exit /b 1
)

set _nt| find /i "%network_to_check%"|find /i "Media disconnected" >nul 2>nul&&(
    echo disconnected
    exit /b 1
) 

echo connected

endlocal
```

Change the name of the network at the beginning and see if this works for you.For better results set the `:` at the end of network name.